# How to query using CAML when a value has < in the value

Tags: caml-query, spservices

I'm using SPServices to query a list, using CAML, and the column I'm searching (Title) have values that contains < and >.

Is there anyway I can use CAML to find these values?  It seems that I'm getting undefined returned.  If the string doesn't contain these characters, I get exactly what I want back.

Using U2U CAML Query Builder, it returns this CAML:

```
<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Title" /><Value Type="Text">Value &lt; 10</Value></Eq></Where></Query>
```

where the value of title is actually **Value < 10**.

Thank you very much,

dave

---

Here is my solution that worked for me.

```
var a = "Test & < > '10'"; 

var newA = a.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g,"&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;").replace(/'/g,"&#039;").replace(/"/g, "&quot;");
```

Then I pass in newA to my SPServices call where I'm using CAML to find my data.

```
CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='title'/><Value Type='Text'>" + newA + "</Value></Eq>" ....
```

Comment: I'm trying something like this:

var a = "Value < 10";
var newA = a.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g,"&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;").replace(/'/g,"&#039;").replace(/"/g, "&quot;");

Where I will pass in newA to the CAML query.

Comment: That seemed to have worked.  I know my strings will contain other characters like & < > " ' so I handled that as well.

Comment: That question is about getting the value not setting it.

Comment: Indeed, but the solution to the illegal character problem is the same.

Comment: If i replace the characters like in the solution of that question they will be displayed as is like i noted in my question.

Comment: True. I'd highly recommend my own solution to that question. :)

Comment: @Stuart Pegg You are right! I didn't notice your answer to that question. you deserve an upvote. :)

Comment: Does anybody mind if we merge these two questions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My advice would be to use the CDATA escape, rather than replacing the offending characters one by one:

```
<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Title" /><Value Type="Text"><![CDATA[Value < 10]]></Value></Eq></Where></Query>
```

That should cure most XML special character ills.

Comment: The CDATA option does work.

Comment: @DrZ: Good good.

Comment: I like that. That's an elegant solution.

Comment: does it work with ( and ) ?

Comment: @edelwater It should work with almost anything.

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert the special characters, see an example of code here:
https://devspoint.wordpress.com/2011/01/07/two-quick-javascript-snippets-i-use-everyday/#comments

SharePoint actually has a built-in function for that, called STSHtmlEncode (cf. my comment in the above link).

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint encodes the html before its stored in the field to avoid XSS.

If you want to decode the html in code use *SPEncode.HtmlDecode(item["Title"])*. Or you can also use Jquery for it (to decode on the View Item page) : http://www.prodevtips.com/2008/10/21/jquery-plugin-html-decode-and-encode/

Comment: Thank you for your answer i dont have trouble decoding the information. If i create a caml query with decoded information the result will be applied as is.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I fully get what you are doing, but you might try using the Contains option in lieu of the Eq option. The "<" is just formatted so that you have clean XML. The Contains option will find all items that contain the selected option:

```
<Contains><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>&lt;</Value></Contains>
```

Comment: The value I'm specifically looking for is: Value < 10.  Not just any string that has a < in it.  The < is actually part of the overall value I'm looking for.  Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Ok guys i found the solution.

If i want to update a field with data that contains illegal XML characters using CAML query i need to put these characters within a `<![CDATA[]]>` element.

In the `Title` example above the code will be like this:

```
<Field Name=\"Title\"><![CDATA[<title>]]></Field>
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Query><Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name="Title" /><Value Type="Text">&lt;</Value></BeginsWith></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="Title" Ascending="True" /></OrderBy></Query>
```

its an eg