# Update SharePoint field with XML illegal characters using caml

Tags: caml-query, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to query using CAML when a value has < in the value](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11697/how-to-query-using-caml-when-a-value-has-in-the-value)

I am trying to update a field named `Title` using caml query. The value that i am trying to put is `<title>`.

If i replace the "<" character with `"&lt;"` and the ">" character with `"&gt;"`, when i view the item properties on SharePoint the value of the field `Title` is `&lt;title&gt;`.

How can i fix this.

Thank you for your time.