# CAML Query for items with a text value containing square brackets

Tags: caml-query, custom-list

I'm attempting to query for list items using a value stored in a *plain text* multi-line of text field in a SharePoint 2007 custom list.

My column is named FilePath and contains a value like: `/admin/SiteCollection/Report Library/Reports/Corporate Reports/Final Audit Report [Dec-11].pdf`

I would like to create a CAML query that will return this item. For example:

`<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="FilePath" /><Value Type="Text" >/admin/SiteCollection/Report Library/Reports/Corporate Reports/Final Audit Report [Dec-11].pdf</Value></Eq></Where>`

Problem is... it doesn't work. We have seemingly narrowed it down to an issue with the square brackets. Duplicating the row and removing the square brackets lets us query for the item again.

**How can I query for items using a multi-line of text file which contains square brackets?**

---

Some more research:

- Seems to work OK when a single line of text field contains square brackets
- Using BeginsWith works ok: `<Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name="FilePath" /><Value Type="Text" >/admin/SiteCollection/Report Library/Reports/Corporate Reports/Final Audit Report [Dec-11].pdf</Value></BeginsWith></Where>`
- Using Contains works ok: `<Where><Contains><FieldRef Name="FilePath" /><Value Type="Text" >/admin/SiteCollection/Report Library/Reports/Corporate Reports/Final Audit Report [Dec-11].pdf</Value></Contains></Where>`
- I've tried encoding the square brackets (`&#91;Dec-11&#93;`) and using `<![CDATA[]]>`, both of which work in other queries, but do not help here.

Comment: Does it make any difference if you switch it to a contains and look for something like 11].pdf for testing purposes? http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopmentlegacy/thread/8b442d22-eb56-40d8-a487-a325d3a70626 has some options.

Comment: Just tested it and using `Contains` works fine...

Comment: Just curious if these CAML Building tools give you any insight. CAML doesn't support regex, but I wonder what the tools generate. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648040.aspx

Comment: @Mike I tried it in U2U CAML Query builder and it did not encode the square brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to figure out why `Eq` doesn't work.. so if anyone can figure that out feel free to post an answer and I will accept it.

The workaround is to use `BeginsWith` or `Contains` instead of `Eq`. In my case I think it will work because of how my data is structured but it is not ideal.

Example working queries:

`<Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name="FilePath" /><Value Type="Text" >/admin/SiteCollection/Report Library/Reports/Corporate Reports/Final Audit Report [Dec-11].pdf</Value></BeginsWith></Where>`

U2U query which also works:

`<Where><Contains><FieldRef Name="FilePath" /><Value Type="Note">/admin/SiteCollection/Report Library/Reports/Corporate Reports/Final Audit Report [Dec-11].pdf</Value></Contains></Where>`

Some other interesting info, you can encode the square brackets using their unicode value:

`<Where><Contains><FieldRef Name="FilePath" /><Value Type="Note" >/admin/SiteCollection/Report Library/Reports/Corporate Reports/Final Audit Report &#91;Dec-11&#93;.pdf</Value></Contains></Where>`

Answer (score 1):

Same issue, but with "<".

Try use **STSHtmlEncode** in SP or there is an example with **CDATA**

```
<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="Title" /><Value Type="Text"><![CDATA[Value < 10]]></Value></Eq></Where></Query>
```

[How to query using CAML when a value has < in the value](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11697/how-to-query-using-caml-when-a-value-has-in-the-value)

Comment: I tried encoding the values but it didn't make a difference when using `Eq` (see my last bullet point in my question).