# Query a single line of text filed using CAML <Contain> will return all items

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, development, caml-query, caml

I have a list inside SharePoint online site collection. the list contain a field named `Processed` which is of type single line of text, and only one item have a value inside this field while the other does not have values.

I write this CAL query to get the single item:

```
List oList = context.Site.RootWeb.Lists.GetByTitle(listname);
                CamlQuery camlQuery2 = new CamlQuery();
                camlQuery2.ViewXml = "<Query><Where><Contain><FieldRef Name='Processed'/>" +
                    "<Value Type='String'>Not Processed</Value></Contain></Where></Query>";

                ListItemCollection collListItem2 = oList.GetItems(camlQuery2);
                context.Load(collListItem2);
                context.ExecuteQuery();
                foreach (ListItem li in collListItem2)
```

but this CAML returned all the items, although one item has the correct value, while the other have empty/null value for the Processed field.

Any advice to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using below query in `ViewXml` (Use [internal name](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/) of `Processed` field):

```
<View>
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <Contains>
                <FieldRef Name='Processed'/><Value Type='Text'>Not Processed</Value>
            </Contains>
        </Where>
    </Query>
</View>
```

You can also add below to set the row limit to 1:

```
<RowLimit>1</RowLimit>
```

**official documentations**:

1. [How to: Retrieve List Items](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee534956(v%3Doffice.14)).
2. [Query schema](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/query-schema).

Comment: It does work. You need to use the complete query given in my answer. Include `<view>` also. If that doesn't work then check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870314/sharepoint-list-caml-query-using-contains) or try using `BeginsWith`  like given at: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/56705/caml-query-for-items-with-a-text-value-containing-square-brackets

Comment: worked....thanks