# Character escaping in CAML query (REST call)

Tags: rest, caml-query, jsom, json

I use JS to create a CAML query. When it is generated, it looks like this:

```
@v1 = {"ViewXml":"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='ID'/><FieldRef Name='Title'/><FieldRef
 Name='Designation'/><FieldRef Name='srd_title2'/></ViewFields><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name
='Subject'/>My Value Here<Value Type='Note'>
```

When users attempt to search using values such as "My Hand\Number2" or "Body & Styles", I receive errors such as "An unrecognized escape sequence '\' was found in a JSON string value". I changed the code to do a manual replacement (e.g., `param.replace("\\","\\\\")`, and that worked for back slashes. But is there a good way to make sure I'm checking for all of these? I tried using CDATA such as in this example: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/11703/24039 to no avail.

update: I actually used `val.(/\\/g, "\\\\")` as Wrapping "val" in encodeURI or encodeURIComponent is not working for this case. I didn't realize the double \ became escaped when I submitted the question, so I wrapped it in a code block now. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the build-in JS functions of SharePoint to work with these kind of errors. Try using `escapeProperly()`

Here is a page that lists some of those functions: https://praneethmoka.wordpress.com/2012/01/12/some-useful-javascript-variablesfunctions-in-sharepoint/

Comment: Thank you. Please see my updated question and my response to @ECM4D 's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in SharePoint 2013 REST special characters are escaped using HTML encoding in query string. If you are using JavaScript try using `encodeURIComponent` method to format your CAML query variable value.

More about it: http://www.sharepointyammertech.com/2014/12/sharepoint-2013-how-to-handle-special.html

Comment: I've done this and it doesn't work. The issue is that it needs to be printed "as escaped." since that's the only way SP will accept it in CAML. I made a mistake in my original question - I had to use `val.(/\\/g, "\\\\")`.  Does this help my question wording?